# Caching/compiling complex Linq query (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a complex Entity Framework query. My performance bottleneck is not actually querying the database, but translating the IQueryable into query text.

My code is something like this:

```
var query = context.Hands.Where(...)
if(x)
    query = query.where(...)
....
var result = query.OrderBy(...)
var page = result.skip(500 * pageNumber).Take(500).ToList(); //loong time here, even before calling the DB

do
{
    foreach(var h in page) { ... }

    pageNumber += 1;
    page = result.skip(500 * pageNumber).Take(500).ToList(); //same here
}
while(y)
```

What can I do? I am using DbContext (with SQLite), so I can't use precompiled query (and even then, it would be cumbersome with query building algorithm like this).

What I basically need, is to cache a "page" query and only change the "skip" and "take" parameters, without recompiling it from the ground up each time.

Comment: How long is 'long time'? And could you show the entire linq query?

Answer (score 4):

Your premise is incorrect.  Because you have a `ToList` call at the end of your query you *are* querying the database where you've indicated, to construct the list.  You're not deferring execution any longer.  That's why it takes so long.  You aren't spending a long time constructing the query, it's taking a long time to go to the database and actually execute it.

If it helps you can use the following method to do the pagination for you.  It will defer fetching each page until you ask for the next one:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Paginate<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> query, int pagesize)
{
    int pageNumber = 0;

    var page = query.Take(pagesize).ToList();
    while (page.Any())
    {
        yield return page;
        pageNumber++;
        page = query.Skip(pageNumber * pagesize)
            .Take(pagesize)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

So if you had this code:

```
var result = query.OrderBy(...);
var pages = result.Paginate();//still haven't hit the database

//each iteration of this loop will go query the DB once to get that page
foreach(var page in pages)
{
    //use page
}
```

If you want to get an `IEnumerable<IQueryable<T>>` in which you have all of the pages as queries (meaning you could add further filters to them before sending them to the database) then the major problem you have is that you don't know how many pages there will be.  You need to actually *execute* a given query to know if it's the last page or not.  You either need to fetch each page as you go, as this code does, or you need to query the count of the un-paged query at the start (which means one more DB query than you would otherwise need).  Doing that would look like:

```
public static IEnumerable<IQueryable<T>> Paginate<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> query, int pagesize)
{
    //note that this is hitting the DB
    int numPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(query.Count() / (double)pagesize);

    for (int i = 0; i < numPages; i++)
    {
        var page = query.Skip(i * pagesize)
                .Take(pagesize);
        yield return page;
    }
}
```

Comment: He didn't say that line didn't call the db, but that it takes a long time before it calls the db. He could be profiling it and seeing when the sql call was actually made.

Comment: @Ocelot20 I doubt it; at the very least I'll wait for the OP to specifically state that before believing it.  I read his comment as indicating he doesn't think the DB should be called there, but it will be.  If he wanted to verify that the work is in constructing the query without hitting the DB then by far the easiest way to test that is to actually construct the query, without executing it at all, and then timing that.  It's very hard to do that when it's all done on one line.

Comment: Also, the construction of the queryable and transformation to SQL is certainly not the bottleneck. Entity Framework (latest version, at least) caches query per AppDomain. Event though the first pass might be longer (we're really talking milliseconds here), it won't in the subsequent queries.

Comment: @Ocelot20 is right.
I don't have specific measurements for building the query (executing it is around 50 ms), building it takes considerably long, because it contains '.Contains()' statement and LINQ convert it to 'IN' in an very inefficient manner.

Also, I don't have access to EF 5, so I don't (probably) have an option for automated cashing.

Comment: @quarion So how are you going about determining how much of the time is spent building the query versus executing it against the database?  Also, if you have an `in` clause with a non-trivial number of items you probably want to look into create a temporary table and joining that table for your query, especially if you're using that check multiple times (at least once for each page).